# Can Amazon Echo OAuth take an authorization url that is a registered domain name?

Tags: oauth, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I am trying to set up OAuth with the Amazon Echo. Unfortunately, I get the error,

```
Error: A URL must be between 9 and 2000 characters.
```

When I try to set up OAuth/account linking on the Amazon Developer portal. It seems to be an issue with my authorization url I am giving Amazon.

[image]

I substituted out the actual url for privacy.

When I visit the url (a web page that is served through a Flask application), everything works fine. My thought is that since the url is not a registered domain name, maybe Amazon won't let me use that url.

When I looked at [Amazon's documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html#h2_login) their example URL has a similar length to mine which is why I think the error may be a bit misleading.

[image]

What could be causing this error and how can I go about fixing it? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is failing since your page is not served via HTTPS. The documentation states, along with other items, 'It must be served over HTTPS.'

Comment: Oh, no way. I will look into that and get back to you. Thank you for answering!